# Auto change variable by Time in PHP and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, variables, time, increment

actually i'm making a web-application in PHP using mysql.
this web-application is for manage people works in a company, there's a table in the database called 'employe' where there's all the informations about someone working in the company, and i have to auto change (increment) 'echelon' attribute every 2 years (exemple from 1 to 2).
I don't know the idea, how to do this .. please I REALLY NEED HELP from you guys.. 
And Thanks.. !!

Answer (score 2):

In mysql you can add event. In phpmyadmin you can see the option to add event.
In that you can add the increment code.

```
update `table_name` set `echelon`=`echelon`+1;
```

For more information about event please refer.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html

This is the code that you can add event for every 2 year.

```
CREATE EVENT `your_even_name` ON SCHEDULE EVERY2YEAR ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO UPDATE  `table_name` SET  `echelon` =  `echelon` +1;
```